# Find variable in array - batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I want to create a shortcut based on the windows username via a batch file

i was thinking along the lines of:

```
if %username% in (a,b,c,d) (
    shortcut ShortcutName DestinationPath
)
else (
    shortcut OtherShortcutName OtherDestinationPath
)
```

I'm having issues with the first part as I already know how to create shortcuts via command line...

Hope I can find some help.

Answer (score 5):

There is not really an array type in batch files, but we can fudge it by iterating over a space-separated list with `for`:

```
@ECHO OFF
set Array=Peter James Robby Jimmy

for %i in (%array%) do (if %i==%USERNAME% (echo %USERNAME% is found) else (echo %USERNAME% not found))
```

If Robby is logged in, output is:

```
Not found
Not found
Robby is found
Not found
```

Comment: Does not work for me (on Windows 7). I get the following error: `"arrayi" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.`

Comment: Changing to `for %%i in (%array%) do (if %%i==%USERNAME% (echo %USERNAME% is found) else (echo %USERNAME% not found))` made it working

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL 
if defined Array[%username%] (
    shortcut ShortcutName DestinationPath
) else (
    shortcut OtherShortcutName OtherDestinationPath
)
```

---

some more code to get it more clearly:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL 
set "Array[Peter]=true"
set "Array[James]=true"
set "Array[Robby]=true"
set "Array[Jimmy]=true"

set "MyUserName=Jimmy"
call:check "%MyUserName%"
set "MyUserName=Paul"
call:check "%MyUserName%"
goto:eof

:check
if defined Array[%~1] (
    echo %~1 is in the array.
) else (
    echo %~1 is NOT in the array.
)
exit /b
```

.. output is:

```
Jimmy is in the array.
Paul is NOT in the array.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for %%i in (a b c d) do (^
 if %%i'==%username%' (shortcut ShortcutName DestinationPath &goto isuser)^
)
rem else
shortcut OtherShortcutName OtherDestinationPath

:isuser
rem other code...
```

Comment: whoa... will the downvoters please tell me where I went wrong? please comment.